# How to pass a function prop to be used within react-table's columns

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am trying to pass a function to be used within ReactTable. Note that I'm referring specifically to https://react-table.js.org/

This is what I've attempted.
I defined MyFunctionCallback() in the parent of MyWrapper, and pass it through to ReactTable, for example:

```
<ReactTable
    MyFunctionCallback  = this.props.MyFunctionCallback
    data                = etc
    columns             = etc...
/>
```

and use it like this...

```
class MyWrapper extends Component{

    render() {

       var rowsArray = this.props.MyDataArray

       var colsDef = [
        {
          Header: "First name",
          accessor: "fname"
        },
        {
          Header: "Last name",
          accessor: "lname"
        },
        {
          Header: "Select",
          Cell: ({row}) => (<a href='#' onClick={(row) => this.props.MyFunctionCallback('abc', row._original.ID)}> View
                                </a>
                            )
        }
      ]

       return (
            <ReactTable
                    MyFunctionCallback = this.props.MyFunctionCallback
                    data ={rowsArray}
                    columns ={colsDef}
                    ...etc...
            />

        ); //end-return
    } //end-render
}

export default MyWrapper;
```

Almost works.. except this is not the correct way of doing it, otherwise i would not be asking the question.

How to do it? (please keep it simple, don't need any fancy HOC :-)

**Update**

1. onClick={(row) => etc... should read onClick={() => etc...
2. use accessor: 'ID' so that you don't have to use row._original.ID, simply do row.ID

so corrected section should be:

```
{
  Header: "Select",
  accessor: "ID",
  Cell: ({row}) => (
    <a href='#' onClick={() => this.props.MyFunctionCallback('abc', row.ID)}>
        View
    </a>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine in your code except

Change

```
     <ReactTable
                MyFunctionCallback = this.props.MyFunctionCallback //this is not required
                data ={rowsArray}
                columns ={colsDef}
                ...etc...
        />
```

To

```
   <ReactTable
                data ={rowsArray}
                columns ={colsDef}
                ...etc...
        />
```

Comment: Thank you. The main issue I had was declaring colsDef outside MyWrapper component. It works in most cases for static strings, but in my case this.props was being injected into the cols defn, and it could not be found ! Once i wrote the question, i moved it inside MyWrapper, hence the reason you could not find much wrong with it :-)